# get records of interval of dates between start date and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two dates start date and end date .
How can I know if between these two dates , I got 01/01 meaning new year .

For example :

```
Table test 
id  start date    End date 

1   02/03/2013   19/09/2016
2   15/02/2015   30/06/2015
```

Output

```
id  start date    End date  
1   02/03/2013   31/12/2013
1   01/01/2014   31/12/2014
1   01/01/2015   31/12/2015
1   01/01/2016   19/09/2016
2   15/02/2015   30/06/2015
```

How to do something like that ?

Comment: Can you show what you've tryed so far?

Comment: Your question ("How can I know if between these two dates?") and your results are not consistent.  Which do you really want?

Comment: Apparently you don't want to know if there's a New Year between but to add one new record for the full year if the timespan  outreaches one year. Isn't that a completely different question? Try to explain it better and show what you've tried.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes , exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would know if the *year* component is different:

```
select t.*,
       (case when year(startdate) < year(enddate) then 1
             else 0
        end) as HasNewYear
from table t;
```

Comment: Although this answers the question, it does not show how to get the result. +1

Comment: @TimSchmelter . . . I was paying attention to the question as written "How can I know if between these two dates".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to find all years between the two dates, then cast out the dates to `DATETIME` objects to get the desired output:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ID, DATEPART(YEAR, STARTDATE) AS YR, ENDDATE
FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, YR+1, ENDDATE
FROM CTE
WHERE YR < DATEPART(YEAR,ENDDATE))
SELECT A.ID, CASE WHEN CAST(A.YR AS VARCHAR)+'-01-01' > B.STARTDATE THEN CAST(A.YR AS VARCHAR)+'-01-01' ELSE B.STARTDATE END AS STARTDATE, CASE WHEN CAST(A.YR AS VARCHAR)+'-12-31' < B.ENDDATE THEN CAST(A.YR AS VARCHAR)+'-12-31' ELSE B.ENDDATE END AS ENDDATE
FROM CTE AS A
JOIN TABLE1 AS B
ON A.ID=B.ID
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Comment: But to be fair, it makes my head spin how people ever get into this position. If I had a sterling pound for every time I saw a bad database model, as in people asking how to change something that's already (incorrectly) in place, I'd be rich.